# Button Click Event Not Working In Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

SOLVED : The latest update solved the problem somehow.

I am experiencing a very odd problem. Whenever I click(tap) the button on my Monodroid app, nothing happens!(I can just hear the tick sound and nothing else).

Let me clarify that things have been going very well before, but today I have been experiencing this unusual problem. Following is the code.

```
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        ProgressBar progressbar = FindViewById<progressbar>(Resource.Id.progressbar1);
```

Now I've tried to fire click event in three following ways,

```
       button.Click +=new EventHandler(button_Click);

       button.Click +=(sender,e)=> {//stuff;};

       button.Click += delegate {//stuff; };
```

In all of the methods, if I update the method (like changing the button's text), it works but if I try to do anything else it doesn't work.

What I've tried that doesn't work in the above mentioned handlers:-

```
       Toast.MakeText(this, "blabla", ToastLength.Long);

       progressbar.visibility = viewstates.visible   etc
```

This button click event has been working fine!, even I has one app implementing the above mentioned tasks which worked but upon re-compiling from visual studio and installing the app on device, it didn't work.

Yes!, I have restarted my PC, Android device, made new programs to test the functionality but it didn't work!.

I have tried the above both on an emulator and Android device( Galaxy S2). I have used both Visual Studio and MonoDevelop and I get the same result. Please help, this is a really odd problem. I have never faced such click event handling in years until now.

Comment: "In all of the methods, if I update the method (like changing the button's text), it works but if I try to do anything else it doesn't work." Does this mean that the event is getting triggered but there are simply some things that don't work once it is triggered?

Comment: @joates yes, the above two methods which I have written (Toast, progressbar) don't work. The code was working fine 2 days ago but yesterday something happened. I made new monodroid projects implementing the same functionality but that doesn't work either. I also used MonoDevelop but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!, the latest update solved the problem.